# Javascript RegEx matching a string inside HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, expression

I've got a pretty weird situation here. I have got a string that looks something like this:

```
<tag&nbsp;class="bla">hey&nbsp;there&nbsp;</tag>
```

I have to use javascript to replace all the `&nbsp;` contained inside the HTML tags with spaces. There can be any amount of tags and `&nbsp;`. So it has to look like this:

```
<tag class="bla">hey&nbsp;there&nbsp;</tag>
```

Thanks in advance,
Arthur.

Comment: People seriously need to stop linking to that answer for the sake of "regex omg why would you use regex on html". As for the OP - are your html entities (&nbsp;) always ending with `;` (so - they're not malformed)?

Comment: adeneo - nope, thanks.

Comment: @eithedog - nope, there's a reason people keep linking and upvoting that answer, using regex to parse HTML is always a bad idea.

Comment: eithedog - yes, they always end with ;

Comment: adeneo - I am not exactly parsing HTML. It's a part of a bigger problem and I just simplified it for the question's sake

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do that at all. It rarely makes sense to work with corrupted data like this. I would attempt to correct it at an earlier level.

Comment: So what exactly did you try?

Comment: @RoToRa - nope, there's no way around it. It's not corrupted, it's a platform limitation. But for whatever reason I'm required to do this.

Comment: If you really need to do it, then the proper solution would be writing your own HTML parser that supports this "syntax".

Comment: Well, if you think you just have to `str.replace(/&nbsp;/, ' ')`, but just inserting the tag into an element will make the browser parse the entities for you, which sounds like a better idea

Comment: @Iserni - well I tried different regular expressions, but I obviously failed. RegEx is definitely not my strong side, so I turned to StackOverflow regex ninjas

Comment: For everyone saying stuff about browsers and parsing - it's a part of a bigger problem and I just simplified it for the question's sake. It doesn't even involve browsers and HTML. So please, do not show your superior web development skills, but just focus on the question. Pretend it's not HTML and just a damn string.

Comment: @ArthurFromLatvia Got that. But for the sake of other people passing by, I still included the standard Tony-the-Pony disclaimer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly not the most efficient, but should do the job:

`str.replace(/<([^>]+)>/g, function(m){ return m.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' '); });`

Which should only touch the `&nbsp;` inside of `<>`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/&nbsp;/g` in internal regexp?

Comment: Thanks, I will take it from here myself now!

Answer (score 1):

First off let's state again that when parsing (X)HTML with regex is the right answer, it's probably because the question is seriously messed up. In this case you should get the guy who generated the corrupted HTML, and make him put his nose in it, then make him fix the mess.

Otherwise, among other things, it will become *your* work, and you'll accept responsibility for any further mess.

That said, maybe the safest approach would be to look for

```
<([^<>]*)&nbsp;([^<>]*)>
```

and replace it with `<\1 \2>`. The downside of this approach is that you will have to do this *repeatedly* (if you have a tag with eight `&nbsp;`'s inside, you'll have to iterate the replacement eight times).

So you'll also need a loop that performs the replace, and if the replaced text is identical to what it was before, then you're done and may exit the loop.

This is not the most efficient way in terms of replacement speed, but it's more straightforward and simpler to handle. Also it helps in remembering that this is a kludgy fix :-)

The problem described in RoToRa's comment may be fixed in this particular case by modifying the outer expression:

```
<(\w[^<>]*)&nbsp;([^<>]*)>
```

so that it only accepts tags starting with a letter. `1 < 2 &nbsp; > 3` would then be rejected.

The same "fix" applies to Ross McLellan's solution:

```
str.replace(/<(\w[^>]+)>/g, function(m){ return m.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' '); });
```

For performance's sake, Ross's solution is faster on small HTML chunks, and falls behind mine when the number of tags grow. That's because the search overhead is marginally larger for my solution, but then mine finds far fewer matches and fewer calls to `replace()` are actually made.

This modification *might* get the best of both worlds, but I haven't tested it:

```
str.replace(/<(\w[^<>]*&nbsp;[^<>]*)>/g,
    function(m) {
        return m.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');
    }
);
```

Comment: I know it's a big mess, but I really do not have a choice here :( Thanks!

Comment: @ArthurFromLatvia Just a word of warning: This will remove the non-breaking spaces in a situation like: `1 < 2 &nbsp; 3 > 2` (Yes, that's invalid HTML, but that's what you are working with).

Comment: @RoToRa, thanks for pointing this out. Added some considerations.